# Why is the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(e^{\frac{\pi i j n}{N}}\right)^2=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The background to this question is it's the proof that $\|\cos\left(\frac{jn\pi}{N}\right)\|=\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}$ and  $\|\sin\left(\frac{jn\pi}{N}\right)\|=\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}$ asked by question 7 [here](https://1drv.ms/b/s!At8Jnu5p-fSJhdh_vAnqyO-x6aZvjA). My question is why is [RED 1](https://1drv.ms/i/s!At8Jnu5p-fSJhdkAfdHcpa8JRky-Hw) =0 and why are RED 2a and 2b both separately equal to zero? It's not obvious to me from the proof. I recognize that it's true from the orthogonality of the Cos/Sin series These are the Discrete sin/cos pair so $\cos\left(\frac{jn\pi}{N}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x_h}{l}\right)$ when converting back to the continuous fourier series which are orthogonal after integrating, but as stated in the proof, this conclusion is what is asked to be proven, so I'm not seeing in the proof how it was proven. Also this question is from Gockenbach Partial differential equations ch. 12.1 or 9.1 depending on the edition.

Comment: This is not always true. If $\frac{ij}{N}$ is an integer then the sum is $N$. In the document linked we have the extra assumption $i,j < N$.

Comment: @Winther, I think you have typos in your comment: isn't the "$i$" in this situation a square root of $-1$?

Comment: Yes, but the comment is still correct. In this book j is an the index into the location along the x-axis where the $f_j$ value is known and n is an index of the frequency at which the amplitude of f at j at the frequency is calculated. if j=N, the sum will become N

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes indeed. Written in a hurry, thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} x^n = \frac{1 - x^N}{1-x}$$ when $x\neq 1$, we see $$\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} e^{2 \pi i j n/N} = \frac{1 - e^{2\pi i j n}}{1 - e^{2 \pi i j/N}} = 0$$ since $e^{2\pi i jn} = 1$ and $e^{2\pi i j/N} \neq 1$.

Comment: Oh, it was right in front of me. I got stuck on the $e^{2\pi i j}=1$ and forgot about the geometric sum. What about red 2. Do you see in the proof why that equals zero?

Comment: 2a and 2b must be zero because they are the real an imaginary parts of $$\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} e^{2\pi i j n/N}$$ which is equal to zero.